# How to combine two d3 objects into one for bulk operations

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm creating some static SVG elements with d3.js and they share a lot of properties.

```
var c1 = svg.append('circle').attr('r',20);
var c2 = svg.append('circle').attr('r',40);
...
```

I want to group these together to set other attributes. I thought that I could use push, i.e.

```
var circles = svg.append('circle').attr('r',20);
circles.push( svg.append('circle').attr('r',40));
...
circles.attr('stroke','black').attr('stroke-width',2);
```

but that errors ("this.setAttribute is not a function")

d3 is all about sets of stuff, and it's [all about arrays](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays), so I thought this work work? Is there a way?

(I know I could do a data join but I'm wondering about a more generic case of manipulating several things at once)

Comment: No need for an array, just do a selection after you're done adding all the elements: `var circles = svg.selectAll("circles");`.

Comment: Thanks, but if I have to use a selector I need to provide selectable identifiers/grouping info on each node and assume a common parent (or do a full search on whole document as which is inefficient). There must be a way to append a given node/d3 object to an existing selection...

Comment: Not without hacking it (the API doesn't provide a function for this). This case usually doesn't arise because when you're using D3's data matching you don't need to dynamically "grow" a selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do things this way, you need to know how a **`d3.selection`** differs from an **`Array`**.

Mike Bostock wrote up a good explanation of the topic [**HERE**](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#subclass).

Here are the important bits:

> You were probably told that selections are arrays of DOM elements. False. For one, selections are a *subclass* of array; this subclass provides methods to manipulate selected elements, such as setting attributes and styles.
>
> ...
>
> Another reason selections aren’t literally arrays of elements is that they are *arrays of arrays* of elements: a selection is an array of groups, and each group is an array of elements.

So, it turns out the Array that you want to `.push` to is actually nested within the Array-subclass that represents the selection. If your selection is stored in the variable `circles` you can access the actual Array of elements as `circles[0]`.

Another important thing to note: the inner Array holds the actual DOM element reference, not a selection of it. To get the element reference from a selection containing a single element, simply call `.node()` on the selection.

You could start by creating an empty selection:

```
var circles = d3.selectAll('.empty');
```

That's a nice, semantic way to do it assuming you don't have anything classed "empty" on your page.

Then you can `.push` the `.node` of each circle selection that you `.append` directly into `circles[0]`:

```
circles[0].push(svg.append('circle').attr('r',40).node());
```

Do this as many times as you want, and then you can set styles/attributes for all of your circles by calling standard selection methods on `circles`:

```
circles
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('stroke-width', 2)
```

[**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/1hL8s9t8/) is a demo.

Comment: Oh yeah, that works. As does `c1[0].push(c2[0][0]); c1.attr(...);`. Thanks! I'm new to d3 but I like to know how things work, so this might not be the best way to do things, but it helps me learn. Many thanks for such a complete answer, example included!

Answer (score 1):

I think an alternative way is to select by multiple classes, e.g.,

```
d3.selectAll(".class1,.class2").attr('...', '...')...
```

We can simply assign two selections with different classes or the same class (if you needn't treat them separately).